# Container returning wrong cached object fix

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, struts2

I have a webserver running Tomcat 7.0, Struts 2, Tiles 2, and Hibernate.  Most of the time everything is fine but occasionally the server returns the wrong cached images/files.  I've confirmed this behavior with several other users and amongst all the major browsers IE, FireFox, Chrome.

Essentially, sometimes the server returns image b, where the html code clearly is coded image-a.jpg.  A shift reload flushes the wrong image and the correct image is then loaded.  To clarify no image files or html files have to be updated to force the server to serve the correct image; a shift+reload seems to do the trick?

This behavior seems to affect images, as well as html files (sometimes the server tries to serve a .jpg as an html file)

website in question: www.mycity-online.com

Comment: how the images being served or cached is not related to S2 or Hibernate.are you using any caching mechanism?

Comment: I use ecache for hibernate objects, but nothing for the images (static content)

Answer (score 0):

Well try using these  in your htmls  head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

Alternatively you could set these headers programmatically while flushing out the response

Comment: I'll try this and report the results.  This has proven to be a pesky problem to find and destroy indeed.  Thanx for the advice